# On Form Submission compare values in Inventory and if it matches, tick a box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a script that compares the Serial number of the submitted form to my inventory sheet, and if it matches tick a box. It currently works when I edit it in the sheet but not when I submit the form, any help would be appreciated :)

[Form Script]:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
      var formResponsesSheetName = "Form Responses";
      var targetSheetName = "Inventory"; 
    
      const formResponsesSheet = 
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL').getSheetByName('Form responses')
      const targetSheet = 
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL').getSheetByName('Inventory');  
      
      if (formResponsesSheet && targetSheet) {
       var valueToCompare = [6];
       
       let targetColumn = targetSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();
       let checkboxColumn = targetSheet.getRange("D:D");
       let checkboxValues = checkboxColumn.getValues();
    
       for (var i = 0; i < targetColumn.length; i++) {
         if (targetColumn[i][0] === valueToCompare) {
           checkboxValues[i][0] = true;
         } else {
            checkboxValues[i][0] = false;
         }
    }
}
```

[Form Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq6vK.png)

[Sheets Script]:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Form responses");
  var range = e.range;
  
  if (sheet.getName() === "Form responses" && range.getColumn() === 7) {
    var valueToCompare = range.getValue();
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Inventory");
    var targetColumn = targetSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();
    var checkboxColumn = targetSheet.getRange("D:D");
    var checkboxValues = checkboxColumn.getValues();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < targetColumn.length; i++) {
      if (targetColumn[i][0] === valueToCompare) {
        checkboxValues[i][0] = true;
      } else {
        checkboxValues[i][0] = false;
      }
    }
    
    checkboxColumn.setValues(checkboxValues);
  }
}
```

[Sheet Triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spDY6.png)

And if you require any more information, please let me know
All the best

Comment: Do not use a screenshot for your script.  This makes it very difficult to provide an answer.  Script should be in text format to allow people who would otherwise help you to copy the script in order to test and/or modify it.  Having to write out the entire script when it could be otherwise copied and pasted is not a practical use of one's time.  See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Have you tried to put any `console.log` in the core of the onFormSubmit function to see if it is actually executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onMyFormSubmit(x) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ns = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const idx = ns.indexOf(Number(x.values[1]));
  if(~idx) {
    sh.getRange(idx + 2,2).setValue("TRUE");
  }
}
```

Sheet0: After submitting a 1 and a 5 in first question which was just a short answer question.

[image]

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Hey Cooper, Thanks for this answer and your previous comments - This has helped massively and I have successfully been able to resolve the issue per your answer. Thanks again :)